# Adding a virtual monitor to xrdp to allow dual monitors

Tags: xorg, xrdp, rdp, remmina

I have two Linux systems (Server, and client). I am using Remmina on my client to remotely connect to the server which has xrdp (Session: xorg). The server is not connected to any monitor. Everything is working perfectly.

I am planning to use my second monitor (on the client-side) since Remmina now is supporting multi-monitors. I would like to use two monitors. Is that possible? How can I do this?